# If $U,D$ are $\kappa$-complete nonprincipal ultrafilters on $\kappa$ and $j_U = j_D$, is $U=D$?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Here, $j_U$, $j_D$ are the canonical elementary embeddings induced by the measures $U,D$ on $\kappa$.

I actually wish to ask three related questions.

Let Ult$_U(V)$, Ult$_D(V)$ be the transitive collapses of the ultrapowers of the universe $V$ mod $U,D$ respectively.

1) If $j_U = j_D$, is $U=D$?

2) If Ult$_U(V)$ = Ult$_D(V)$, is $U = D$?

3) If $j_U(U) = j_D(D)$, is $U=D$?

As you can see, these all revolve about the soft question, "To what extent can we reconstruct a measure given information about the elementary embedding it induces?"

Comment: The answer is no for 1 if you look at all measures. In fact, two measures give the same embedding iff they are Rudin-Keisler equivalent (i.e. if they only differ by a permutation of the base set). If you restrict to normal measures, however, the answer is yes. I suspect the answer to 2 is no even for normal measures and I have no idea about 3.

Comment: Thank you. The relevant direction of your cited equivalence is clear. I am glad that you addressed the same questions for normal measures, as I was separately curious about that. It is too bad (3) remains mysterious -- it would be nice if we could recover the ultrafilter from its image alone.

Comment: To note, as I've studied more, it is definitely the case that (2) is false, at least for non-normal measures.

Comment: Also to note, (3) is true in $L[U]$ for $U$ some measure on $\kappa$.